# How can I align vertically proportioned with the other text boxes the dropdown button here?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a primaly bootstrap from getbootstrap.com. I want to align properly the account type dropdown here. Also the dropdown list items are not properly aligned to the dropdown button. Please help.Thank you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" align="center"> 
      <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Account type
              <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                  <li><a href="#">Supplier</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="supplieruname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplieruname" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" required></div>
           </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="supplierpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Set Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplierpassword" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" float="right" required></div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="acctype" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Account Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="acctype" placeholder="Company Name" tabindex="3" float="right" required></div>
          </div> 

          
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save">
            <input type="reset" class="btn" name="clear" value="Clear">
            </div>
          </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: Do you want the "username", "setpassword" and so on to be centered ?

Comment: just the dropdown account type should be aligned to the other textbox. I want to adjust the alignment of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Add class `btn-group` to the dropdown.so the dropdown won't get the 100% width.Thus the dropdown menu will be aligned to center.Or  add `display:inline-block` style to the `.dropdown`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" align="center"> 
      <div class="form-group">

          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="dropdown btn-group">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Account type
              <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                  <li><a href="#">Supplier</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="supplieruname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>
           <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplieruname" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" required></div>
           </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="supplierpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Set Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplierpassword" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" float="right" required></div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group"> 
            <label for="acctype" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Account Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="acctype" placeholder="Company Name" tabindex="3" float="right" required></div>
          </div> 

          
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group"><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Save">
            <input type="reset" class="btn" name="clear" value="Clear">
            </div>
          </div>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the time being, you can apply the following come back later to fix.**

Fix it on the page.

```
<style>
.dropdown, .dropup {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
   float:center;
}
.form-group{margin-bottom:20px;}

</style>
```